# index file smaller than expected

Tags: git

This morning, I started getting this error from git:

> fatal: index file smaller than expected
>
> fatal: git status --porcelain failed

Any idea of what is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried this http://vertis.github.com/2012/01/24/git-fatal-index-file-smaller-than-expected.html

Comment: Yes I tried it before posting. The problem was with my submodules that kept corrupting my index file (don't know why).

Comment: @karellm Did you find out _why_ this was happening?

Comment: No to be honest I didn't investigate what caused it and it stopped happening too.

Comment: Tip: In my experience, this can be due to an NFS folder not updating. If your repo is on NFS, just wait a few minutes before attempting to correct the problem. I had this after pulling from one machine, and then checking status on another, both machines mounting the same NFS.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The index file has become corrupted, but it is easily re-creatable. Just remove it...

```
rm .git/index
```

Then you can re-add the files you're trying to stage.

Comment: As said above, it wasn't working because of a conflict with a submodule that was corrupting my index over and over again...
I removed the submodule, removed the index and add all. It finally worked. Thanks!

Comment: Why does this happen? I've had this occur twice in the past fortnight and I can't see a reason for it.

Comment: This did not work for me.  Prior to this error I had a mostly clean working copy.  After removing the index file and running `git add .` it behaved as though every single file was new and needing a commit.

Comment: Doesn't work either when one has a submodule. Just reset (below answer).

Comment: If found that after running this I had to do a `git restore --staged` and it fixed the problem of git thinking everything needed to be recommitted

Comment: Viper's solution worked as a charm for me. Just missed a dot: `git restore --staged .`

Answer (score 114):

If you want to keep local changes, use the following:

```
$ rm .git/index
$ git reset HEAD .

> Unstaged changes after reset:
  modified foo.txt
  modified bar.txt
```

Comment: Any idea why this happens? It's happened to me about 4-5 times over the past fortnight.

Comment: This answer is the best one here.
Additionally, heads up if you use git submodules: Remove those index files as well (they are located in `.git/modules/src`). This had me wondering why the error still occurred after removing the (main) index file.

Comment: I would guess this might happen for standard reasons, process died mid way, out of disk space, etc. Though in my case it could be that I use a symlink to the git folder to create directories to use for building in place of svn externals, though it's strange as the only operation on those repos is read only to hard reset the build folders.

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Answer (score 5):

To those having isses even after removing index and cannot do a reset. If you want to keep your changes do the following (not a solution but rather an ugly workaround!).

1. Make backup of your files, what I am about to say *should* work but do it just in case.
2. Remove the .git folder
3. Clone your repository (does not matter where) I did it in the current directory
4. Copy the created from the clone .git directory into your current directory
5. Remove the cloned directory
   *6.  Optional, if you used a branch checkout to it again*
6. Git status should now track changes as it is supposed to and all your git commands should work

My case was as described above, git had messed up its references... `Git log` was showing "your branch seems to be broken" and `git fsck` was giving me warnings about bad references. Figured if I can probably fix it but I'd spend a lot of time doing it, so I went for the ugly workaround.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. I had submodules in my project; it is important to get them, too with `git clone --recurse-submodules URL` when cloning the repo.