# asdf-vm - Git "index file smaller than expected" error when running `asdf update` how to fix?

Tags: git, asdf-vm

I've been using [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com) for a couple years with great success. However, starting yesterday when I run the `asdf update` command, I get this error:

`fatal: .git/index: index file smaller than expected`

Thanks to @phd's comment, I tried to remove `~/.asdf/.git/index` the ran `git reset HEAD` under `~/.asdf`.

However, now when I run `asdf plugin update --all` for my `asdf` plugins, I get these errors:

```
Updating python to master
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/python/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/python/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/python/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/python/.git'
Updating R to master
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/R/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/R/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/R/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/R/.git'
Updating direnv to master
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/direnv/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/direnv/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/direnv/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/direnv/.git'
Updating nodejs to master
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/.git'
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/[home]/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/.git'
```

I tried removing the `index` files in each of those four `.git` directories and resetting the HEADS in each. But that didn't help.

I have no idea what these errors mean. Can someone please advise on how to troubleshoot and fix this? Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+.git%2Findex%3A+index+file+smaller+than+expected

Comment: Backup everything and then `rm .git/index; git reset HEAD .`

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861198/7976758

Comment: Thank you @phd I tried your suggestion but it seems to have created more problems for asdf. Can you please re-open the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14594665/7976758

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but eventually I removed all the `asdf` plugins and reinstalled them from scratch. This removed the error messages.